# Text Underline Showing Underline

Tags: html, css, underline

I seem to be having a problem with Underline. I have a box that is linkable:

```
<div class="single_box">
   <a href="servicesweprovide.asp"><img src="images/law_enforcement_accreditation.jpg" alt="" />
   <p>Law Enforcement<br />Accreditation</p></a>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.single_box {
    width:253px;
    min-height:170px;
    float:left;
    margin:0px 15px 0 0;
    padding:0px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.single_box p{
    background:url(../images/arrow.png) 92% 50% #0b2e84 no-repeat;
    font:bold 16px/18px  Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#fff;
    padding:6px 14px;
    word-spacing:normal;
    letter-spacing:normal;
    font-stretch:normal;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.single_box p:hover {
    background-color:#ffc210;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

I set it up on JFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/2EHkp/

I have a feeling it has to do with me targeting the `<p>` Paragraph and not the href. But I can't figure out how to target the href instead of the `<p>`. Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Its not allowed to use a block level element (p) inside an inline element (a).

Comment: @LinkinTED - [Actually, that's not true as of HTML5.](http://blog.paciellogroup.com/2011/06/html5-accessibility-chops-block-links/)

Comment: Yeah, you are right, my comment is only true when <HTML5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
.single_box a {text-decoration:none;}
```

Comment: That did it... why didn't I think of that :( uggg Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You need to select the anchor. Instead of the container. http://jsfiddle.net/2EHkp/1/

```
.single_box a {text-decoration:none;}
```

**This is what you had:**

```
.single_box  {text-decoration:none;}
```

Answer (score 1):

text-decoration is underline by default for links.  So, you need to turn that off:

```
.single_box a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to target the href, you may need:

`.single_box a{text-decoration:none;}`

Answer (score 0):

Anchor link ... by default takes underline if you have not using any css like text-decoration:none;

Please add one extra class under your .single_box class

Here is my code :

```
.single_box a{text-decoration:none;}
```